# Populating data on gridview

Tags: android

In my android app, i have a particular scenario, for one of the screens.

I require 2 button,one on each side of the corner(left and right).
Below this i want to populate data in a control.

If left button is clicked, the control should be a gridview.
If right button is clicked , the control should be a listview.

And accordingly the data should be populated.

How should i approach this scenario.
Should i create controls dynamically, or use xml instead

Rgds

Answer (score 0):

Create the view with two different layouts.

Assume that you have 2 xml layouts named gridLayout.xml and listLayout.xml
and that somehow mode is determined earlier in your code and set to one of two constants GRIDVIEW or LISTVIEW.  Than you can use a code fragment like:

```
  private Context        m_Context = activity.getBaseContext();
  private ViewHolder     m_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(m_Context);
```

...

```
  if (mode == GRIDTYPE)
    viewDisplay = m_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridLayout, null);
  } else {
    viewDisplay = m_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.listLayout, null);
```